# Passing a variable to a ->each() function making the variable always = 0 php

Tags: php, laravel

One of the routes I'm making for my API in laravel requires me to pass a variable to a `->each()` function.

This can be seen below:

```
public function by_location($zone_id)
{
    $zone = Zone::where('id', $zone_id)->get()[0];
    error_log($zone->id);
    $exhibitors = Exhibitor::where('zone_id', $zone_id)->get();
    $exhibitors->each(function($exhibitor, $zone)
    {
        error_log($zone->id);
        $exhibitor['zone_info'] = $zone;
    });
    return response()->json($exhibitors);
}
```

This first error_log outputs '2', but with the second I get 'Trying to get property 'id' of non-object'.

Any help is apprecited!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use `$zone` which you selected from database on first line.
Also if you want to change value of item you are iterating you have to use `->map()` instead of `->each()`

> I changed ->get()[0] to ->first(). **Never** use ->get()[0]

```php
public function by_location($zone_id)
{
    $zone = Zone::where('id', $zone_id)->first();
    error_log($zone->id);
    $exhibitors = Exhibitor::where('zone_id', $zone_id)->get();
    $exhibitors->map(function($exhibitor) use ($zone){
        error_log($zone->id);
        $exhibitor['zone_info'] = $zone;
        return $exhibitor;
    });

    return response()->json($exhibitors);
}
```

Comment: map also will not change the item, if you want to change it you must use [transform](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-transform)

Comment: Thank you! your `use` worked perfectly. However, quick question - you say to change the value I need to use `->map` however, in other functions I've been able to use `->each` and it updated the values for me.

Comment: You're right guys. In this case you can change value with all 3 methods above